# ¿Existe una forma de crear un spinner igual que los selectbox de html, que tenga un texto y un value?

Tags: java, android

Pues lo dicho en la pregunta, necesito que los datos de mi spinner tengan un value y text, al igual que sucede son los selectbox en html.Es importante tener un clave valor para que el usuario vea un texto legible y yo pueda enviar un número (que es el value) al servidor. He estado buscando pero no encuentro nada. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Realmente necesitas crear un popup que ocupe toda la pantalla con un select?

Comment: No simplemente lo que quiero es implementar ese spinner como un selectbox, para que el usuario vea un texto y yo pueda enviar al servidor un código en lugar de ese texto

Comment: pues los spinner tienen posicion que son integer,que inicia con el 0, se selecciona con spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener

Comment: @kosode Te sugiero modificar tu pregunta , revisa [ask].

Answer (score -1):

¿Has trabajado con clases?. Lo que quieres lograr podría solucionarse de la siguiente manera.

1. Crea una clase con la que tengas una clave y un valor.
2. Luego crear una lista de esta clase, luego pasar la lista a tu adaptador para el Spinner.
3. Luego obtener el objeto seleccionado en el Spinner.
4. Extraer la clave, y enviarla a la base de datos.

Te dejo esto como guía:

```
public class MyItem {
    private String clave;
    private String valor;

    public MyItem(String clave, String valor) {
        this.clave = clave;
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public String getClave() {
        return clave;
    }

    public void setClave(String clave) {
        this.clave = clave;
    }

    public String getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(String valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.valor;
    }
}
```

Luego crear los items:

```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   //Crear datos de prueba
    ArrayList<MyItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add(new MyItem("clave1", "Valor1"));
    items.add(new MyItem("clave2", "Valor2"));

    //Crear el adaptador para el spinner
    ArrayAdapter<MyItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyItem>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, items);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

Al final solo necesitarías obtener el objeto del spinner y luego hacer el respectivo get:

```
    MyItem myItem = (MyItem)spinner.getSelectedItem();
    String miClaveParaBD =  myItem.getClave();
```